# Погода шепчет

Tags: фразеология

Почему про плохую погоду говорят "погода шепчет"? Откуда это пошло?

Comment: Позвольте прокукарекать. Это не Лимонов. Вот текст, написанный мною в 1958 году. Погода шепчет, займи и выпей. Ей хочется плакать вдвоём. Земля покрывается снежной сыпью И тотчас же мокнет дождем. О слякоть! Не надо просить меня много. Когда был с тобой не в ладу? Когда не бродил за тобою не в ногу — Споткнешься... И я упаду.... Вот видишь - сегодня я вымок до нитки. И это в последний раз. Мне стыдно валяться в грязи у калитки, Вблизи от любимых глаз. Тем более время не ждет и не терпит, И если в стихах нет огня, И если стихи мои пахнут смертью, Оно не простит меня. Анатолий Зеликма

Comment: Ну мало ли кто и что писал в 1958 г. Вы с тех пор даже правописание не подтянули, цитируете то ли по памяти, то ли по чудом сохранившемуся листочку. То есть вряд ли кто мог у вас позаимствовать. На первоисточник, таким образом, не тянет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Появилась эта поговорка, если верить источнику, в 70-х годах у Лимонова. Кстати, полностью она звучит так: *погода шепчет: займи, но выпей*. Из полного варианта становится понятно, что речь идет о плохой погоде, которая заставляет выпить.

Comment: Хотелпсь бы понать, о каком источнике идет речь. Я поискал у Лимонова и нашел такое: «Погода шепчет — бери расчет!» (Эдуард Лимонов. Подросток Савенко. http://www.net-lit.com/writer/2498/books/55387/limonov_eduard/podrostok_savenko/read/26)

Answer (score 3):

Если просто "погода шепчет", то выражение носит  несколько романтический оттенок. Некую связь с дикой природой. Подразумевается "погода колдует" (шептуны-колдуны, знахарки). Колдовство бывает не только чёрное, но и белое, т. е. хотят сказать, что сегодня в природе что-то магическое, колдовское, к чему-то побуждающее.

Под влиянием Лимонова поговорка превратилась в целое высказывание:" Погода шепчет: займи, но выпей" - т. е. я не хочу, но что-то магическое толкает к этому, типа "бес попутал", всё заставляет это сделать, даже погода. Отговорка такая.

Answer (score 1):

Как говорит интернет, у Лимонова в рассказе "Подросток Савенко" так: "С первыми лучами солнца в сердца шпаны вселяется беспокойство. «Погода шепчет — бери расчет!» — гласит салтовская поговорка, и шпана дружно увольняется с заводов в апреле".
Наверное, сначала было просто "погода шепчет" именно в плане шаманит, колдует. Потом Лимоновское "бери расчет", а потом народное "займи, но выпей". В любом случае это скорее о хорошей, умиротворяющей погоде.